# "Nested" identifier - using the value of one variable in the identifier of another variable. Is this possible?

Tags: php, variables, syntax

Essentially I want to do the following in PHP (or any language for that matter):

```
class Foo 
{
    // some hidden attributes 
    private $num1 = 1;
    private $num2 = 2;
    private $num3 = 3;

    // accessor method that returns a different attribute depending on parameter passed 
    public getNum($num)
    {
        return $num{$num};
    }
} 
$foo = new Foo();
$foo->getNum(2);
// returns 2 (the value of $num2)
```

Rather than using an if-else block/ternary operation or having three separate accessor methods, which seems slower and more cumbersome, it would be nice to "fuse" the identifiers together. I appreciate this might be a stupid question but I am a neophyte so please cut me some slack.

Apologies if this is a duplicate (I did a search in advance).

Comment: `return $this->{'num' . $num}`

Comment: Thanks a lot mate. Any reason why the 'num' is on the left of the concat. operator? Would make more sense to me if it was on the right.

Comment: Doing `'num . $num'` creates a string with ie. value `num2`. This will be interpolated as a variable name using the square brackets. You could also write return `$this->{"num$num"};`. But I think doing that at all is no good practice. What if, that property does not exist? Better use an array / map.

Comment: Ah yes of course, not sure how I got the order confused. 
Good to know.